# An issue while showing a path on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have multiple points of longitude and latitude. For example:

```
1 long lat, starting point   
2 long lat   
3 long lat     
4 long lat
.
.
.
```

.
[image][image]

My code is the following

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
        {
            "title": '1',
            "lat": '30.705911', 
            "lng": '76.679656',
            "description": '1'
        }
    ,
     {
            "title": '2',
            "lat": '30.701713',
            "lng": '76.684097',
            "description": '2'
        },
     {
            "title": '2',
            "lat": '30.703291', 
            "lng": ' 76.701022',
            "description": '2'
        },{
            "title": '2',
            "lat": '30.691888', 
            "lng": ' 76.710721',
            "description": '2'
          }

];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Intialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Intialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                path.push(src);
                poly.setPath(path);
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 800px; height: 800px">
</div>
```

I have faced an issue where lines are connected directly one to third point and one to fourth point.

Comment: Would you please explain what exactly the problem is and what exactly you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Don't push the `src` into the path, it is a duplicate of the first point in the overview path.  Remove this line:

```
path.push(src);
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LL97vsjb/)

code snippet:

```js
var markers = [{
    "title": '1',
    "lat": '30.705911',
    "lng": '76.679656',
    "description": '1'
  }, {
    "title": '2',
    "lat": '30.701713',
    "lng": '76.684097',
    "description": '2'
  }, {
    "title": '2',
    "lat": '30.703291',
    "lng": ' 76.701022',
    "description": '2'
  }, {
    "title": '2',
    "lat": '30.691888',
    "lng": ' 76.710721',
    "description": '2'
  }

];
window.onload = function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var lat_lng = new Array();
  var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var data = markers[i]
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
    lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title
    });
    latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })(marker, data);
  }
  map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

  //***********ROUTING****************//

  //Intialize the Path Array
  var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

  //Intialize the Direction Service
  var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  //Set the Path Stroke Color
  var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
    map: map,
    strokeColor: '#4986E7'
  });

  //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
  for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
      var src = lat_lng[i];
      var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
      // path.push(src);
      poly.setPath(path);
      service.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#dvMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="dvMap" ></div>
```